# How to create a GET-form

Tags: forms

For example a filter form on admin areas can best be GET forms, that way they are bookmarkable and can filters be maintained across pager-pages.

How can one best use form_api for such forms? Will the _validate hooks be submitted? Can the _submit hook be omitted?

For example views-exposed filters work this way; But the code in views handling this is convoluted and complex, too complex to be used as good example for when developing custom interfaces with simple filter forms.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can create or hook_alter any form to grab GET-data, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I've updated the question with a reference to an examlple.

Answer (score 11):

Use the #method parameter of the form like this:

```
<?php
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
?>
```

Comment: Sure. That is one part. But how about validation, submit hooks, and so on. Are the set?

Comment: A form's method must be set to post for it's submit and validate functions to be called implicitly.

Comment: Related: `form_data` keys `always_process` and `method` can also be set in the form definition which results in validate+process hooks being run. But I can't find an example of use for this and I still end up with `form_state` containing a `method` key set to `post`!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question, this is a more complete real-life, yet very simple example :)

you will want to **define the form**

```
function YOURMODULE_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $form['#action'] = '/search';
  $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('mymod-search'));
  $form['search'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 20,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

and then you can **use it**

```
$searchform = drupal_get_form('YOURMODULE_search_form');
$output .= drupal_render($searchform);
```

The last line could be i.e. a block['content'] or whatever you need.

Comment: For search forms, you may want to also put `$form_state['redirect'] = false;` in the submit handler to disable redirecting after the form is submitted.